# How do I write a unit test which makes sure the 'save' action doesn't respond to a 'get' HTTP verb in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing

I have this route defined:

```
match 'me/save' => 'me#save', :via => :post
```

I only want this action method to work with the POST HTTP verb. How do I test to make sure it DOESN'T work with a GET verb? Or is this not even necessary? Currently I have this unit test:

```
test "save doesn't work with get" do
  get :save
  assert_response :error
end
```

However, when I run it, I get an error, rather than a failed test:

```
  1) Error:
test_save_doesn't_work_with_get(MeControllerTest):
NoMethodError: You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
You might have expected an instance of Array.
The error occurred while evaluating nil.[]
    app/controllers/me_controller.rb:19:in `save'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could put this around the code you're testing (that generates the error):

```
assert_raise Exception { the code that does the getting }
```

Whether or not this is necessary, as you ask, depends on **why** you want to test this particular functionality.

If you're testing it to make sure that no one modifies your routes improperly (e.g. accidentally, opening up a security hole), then maybe it's worth it.

On the other hand, if you're writing the test to make sure that Rails is doing it's job, then you're just over testing.

Comment: Yes, I'd be testing to make sure my routes are set up correctly - NOT testing the Rails framework.

Answer (score 1):

Btw, you can just define post in your route instead of match via post, like :

```
post 'me/save' => 'me#save'
```

Now, to test that, you use post instead of get like :

```
test "save doesn't work with get" do
  post :save, :id => ...
  assert_response :error
end
```

where :id is just a posted parameter(if there is any).

However, your error seems to come from the fact that you have a nil object that tries to reference an attribute, somewhere in your save method.

And, btw, it's a bad idea to test Rails(this is what you do by testing match). It's already very extensively tested and it's mostly a waste of your time.

Comment: I get that testing Rails is a waste of my time, but wouldn't I be testing that I've set up my routes correctly (and not screwed something up in my routing later on down the road)? Or is it still a waste of time?

Comment: No, you wouldn't test that. You are testing that a post route works. This is testing rails. Instead, you should test the behaviour of a post. Like after this post, the user must have(1) new article and things like that. If you accidentally change a route, you will understand it because you will get a Rails error. A test would be redundant. My advice, however, is not to worry about routes, but just learn how they work with named routes and more, so to make them more clean and precise(for instance, i never use match, but get or post explicitly).